# Apply selection on overview+detail display in Vega-Lite

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega, vega-lite

I took the overview+display [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvR9CAVgAMtuvFgVIAX3URIFeMvg6zANoaEKAQYVAA7oyaLGYALAActh7hUBhGANZmkOhGyJgp4ZDISj6ajErUZqGpngAe1cG1UABmjMhimtnaeMhqTbWQeACehH04Q2iE3EbopoXNkAhz42AGmtwYFdVLHcjweDwqE+xGrLCIbu4DqTl1jLA7h3hiq5BuNxDXzVDDO20dLoTQhGRjwPqqKAjMbZACOrHQSmeOkYVA+tVcTW+YRqRSiMUuOESyRukBQjGo+DMADYSYN0lkJrl8v1BrA9gcjjtTudCWshqM3hVekYKHM1FASmUKtRHjgApAGgBdVzYopS7jlSqNH6K-7tTrdHQQqGC7K9VDTWamNW3P76T5hSAAw3A0Hg1k-U0wibwxHIw5ohaDdD3OX8w7wDIAYW4rCRZmkkMg1FBQLALTm7MxPxzqTzXw0SpSkB8SjaVX0dweAE0dqgKgBROq9BM4aS2VUgVxAA) and tried to combine it with a rule mark that shows up if the mouse hovers over it. Similar to the selection-nearest [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgB3RgBMW2MADYADMfURIKRtXwHpp81B3o8mHMEisATmIORnrnx43PAA1rB08LAUkAC+jpDISvDcOoxK1AYeAB5ZkABmjMhiOn4ByGpQeACehBU4kHhohNxe6L6x8RqQYujVyF4GANoaEKAQE1AYXqF+EkoVjpOJyanpme6jk1DVeYXFpQ2EXozwi1W19VAAjqzoSnjMLoxUcUvbkClirXtFJX6waqodjcXyqC51PxKbiodLtOJbCCxLZdSbjD6wYrIeCPZRZRETSDpHTIXKbbYfGqQhqwdZiRYE5Z4hqobisTGs17vCkrFJpDKwYaQXIAXW5HwW6C8yFgeAMeC8rGQjLAyIpqI+01m7kalz8LXSco1yySfPW+IpFl2Ov2-yOJzOlV11JudweT0er2NH24hHQ8GY1rAHgo7SVBmMau2UaR73RywV91g+VaqGGKo8hTETUGOvuhzAQyJShJ2To5UqHkx9JxPBUDWJpLiIs6BLFBMgWr8ivpkBRcY7iaUydT6ctwYKjGzAzy+aFjbLFfBVaxteZUAXzdbFPbPK7DSa2Tl4t5awyFstkCDIbDVwAjJHxRZD3KbX8C-4XOdnVdGs1WvCMYTEBUa7lAKRKIUGzBlsf5HrOEjUPWUAnDYx5OGSYAiAArOC-hBth3qQOg2SMLAACaeSwkoACiR5JK+YD2ERsrVL2Oovgh1jIZAqG2HhOiYThAkEduqogLEQA).

[This](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNhgkbXmRWAjAFYALG4AMXgK8ADn8ANlUoWABPVHZuMStIAEE1KBMzVxw3AF91ewhHZ0ywTx9-b2CwiMho2PjElOr08ysAJly7Q0KdYtK-L1CAkIHq2riEnGTU41MWnA8O-IcnHvdvfoB2IarImPGG6ebi6UX87pc1suDtkd26iahGtNni9ryzlYus9f8AThvwnd9pMnjMMu5TvZzr0fh5-JVbjU9vUQYcXlZQpCup8YVdAsNAUj7okAEJo8E4DZYgo4y79CoE0bIh6QMlNdE4E7vKG075XQYIwljFFQNnPClgN6dGlFOn+LaCpnEyZisFzMCY7nY2V8-pBAFK4Gi8nqrzU5Y6ko-Lz-RVAkWsk3FTXSi2rXW+OEG+0s1VHCGdAC6GlOxngyngOistiWUNdS0gAHdGJoWBjfL4tbHcMhGNR8FZpBms7HIMglOHNIwlNQrAZs-lIAAPOvxhuQPBRQjFDtoQjcABOpjUbezkAAZoxkGJNIlZSWG5FI2JivXFwnNNwMNXW+v27Bp8h4HgeCpJuwB6xYIgRAeV8fT5BRw3ss+lubF5B0E3GJZ9G-SxPPAV0SJ893sV9wLASD1w-RsxHQKJkAHaMAIKNDDEgDABwAa13KDMM7btEgkJRXAwiA4LHctK2rWt-wIzConwxijEnadZ0mf0F3Ajsux7ABHVh0CUICdEYKgR1YzCEFMVcKNLAAvZDuCscdTAPBSIK06CeM-cMxEHFjWInKcZ0SYUEj09c+OIyYlC3athx0mCoNc2DrLjRisPQXDEn7as8CkgiywrbgqxrYyoMgbhCHQeBmGYhjpPFdVfBchSqNLO8jxPZQot4vBuHiE9CFvQ8H3y5LpNsntYDokDPPbMjfIsIKcDwS9kCa6iwoi6g-xsZtIEDHrSyqqBUG4K80G4SSxoTPtO0SByyLA1j3L3TaXzGtdeOwvDqpCoiewC0T1rchaoBo8K6IKvdIAMoyju8k6VscpRhyu+xTI4izmQugisrHWL4sS+7ePDJQqzys8HB0n6csquGO2KsRSvK+9YeClLUt6BHdIJtVinS6TgdLJL4dx2rEiEkSxJPeaifY8yuPRDLGO27NyfQ7yDohz83smS9Gp0x74meqBqCHZjMqujshyUWBx0HVBUOkvbvMndHkIF3ikexyYipKxgyoNx8Ca52CFODNyANtnbn010tk1TRB00zADIBQPMCxwUJPYe-nJlazAmpqCrDap3iLyvG9zYm53Bf4xJAuQ9Icd4m7+sGmMTJbG2MKtiDw+zu6XvbFsK8-FnOK0VZ5aFqAXFQfshwSIuxsgSmk-bWvEm4hSacmOnROYcSme879fz1scT3gHCAGFpvOzlvqlgcUzUjTkDlofZJA6ubOUgdVJwdSxE0zmi4A4voI0UaNHFpRJ3o6OjGn2AAE0Cqw6sAFEmwuFXmAIsnQYKvmyEAA) is my spec in the editor, and here for completeness:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": 1541044448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 1},
      {"date": 1541045448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 2},
      {"date": 1541046448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 5},
      {"date": 1541047448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 3},
      {"date": 1541048448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 2},
      {"date": 1541049448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 1},
      {"date": 1541050448046, "symbol": "A", "value": 6},
      {"date": 1541044448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 7},
      {"date": 1541045448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 3},
      {"date": 1541046448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 2},
      {"date": 1541047448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 6},
      {"date": 1541048448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 4},
      {"date": 1541049448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 6},
      {"date": 1541050448046, "symbol": "B", "value": 1}
    ]
  },
  "vconcat": [
          {
            "width": 600,
            "height": 300,
            "encoding": {
              "x": {
                "type": "temporal",
                "field": "date",
                "scale": {
                  "domain": {
                    "selection": "brush-selection"
                  }
                },
                "axis": {
                  "title": ""
                }
              }
            },
            "layer": [
              {
                "mark": {
                  "type": "line"
                },
                "encoding": {
                  "y": {
                    "field": "value",
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "scale": {
                      "zero": false
                    }
                  },
                  "color": {
                    "field": "symbol",
                    "type": "nominal"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "mark": "point",
                "encoding": {
                  "opacity": {
                    "value": 0
                  }
                },
                "selection": {
                  "tooltip-selection": {
                    "type": "single",
                    "nearest": true,
                    "encodings": ["x"],
                    "on": "mousemove",
                    "empty": "none"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "mark": {
                  "type": "point"
                },
                "encoding": {
                  "color": {
                    "type": "nominal",
                    "field": "symbol"
                  },
                  "opacity": {
                    "condition": {
                      "selection": "tooltip-selection",
                      "value": 1
                    },
                    "value": 0
                  },
                  "y": {
                    "type": "quantitative",
                    "field": "value"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "mark": {
                  "type": "rule",
                  "color": "gray"
                },
                "transform": [
                  {
                    "filter": {
                      "selection": "tooltip-selection"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "width": 600,
            "height": 60,
            "mark": "area",
            "selection": {
              "brush-selection": {
                "type": "interval",
                "encodings": [
                  "x"
                ]
              }
            },
            "encoding": {
              "x": {
                "field": "date",
                "type": "temporal"
              },
              "y": {
                "field": "value",
                "type": "quantitative",
                "axis": {
                  "tickCount": 3,
                  "grid": false
                },
                "scale": {
                  "zero": false
                }
              }
            }
          }
  ],
  "config": {
    "axisY": {
      "minExtent": 30
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected behaviour:**

When I select an interval in the overview chart, the detail chart rescales its domain and when I hover over the detail chart the rules nearest to the date points show up.

**Actual behaviour:**

The rules show up correctly when no interval selection is applied. After selecting an interval on the overview chart, the rules just show up if the mouse hovers in the range of the interval, drawn on the overview chart, as if the selection for the rules is looking for the nearest points from the overview.

**My guess:**

The scale of the "tooltip-selection" does not take the actual scale of the detail chart to determin where the nearest points are. How can I achive this?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Vega/Vega-Lite: I would suggest filing an issue with the project: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues

Comment: Thanks, as I wrote an issue I found [this one](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4265#issue-382392741), which has exactly the same problem. I hope a fix will be there soon.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/pull/4289 and works now. See [this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNgD9w5G15kVgIwBWACweADD5BPgAcgQBs6k7OsACeqOzcYlaQAIJqdk7GpuaemRAAvlFOjtEuOu443n6BvqERxWVxCUkp6Y1ZJmaVYABM+WBFA6VZrj3VAT7hQWFTHfaQzYnJOGkZ0UZduTheA0PRIwtjnr6TAOwzDQNGS62r7ddQWz3Se-MOj+VuJzWhl3OfW4rKAPDZPHI9frRfYlT7HKqnQIATn+kUB8WWbXWG2y3Ty0Peh2c8LAE38XkC9QBYMWGLuIOxZWeVnCb2GcIqP0mwVmaJpQJSACFGZ0IVYzmyDhzvgjfnVee8bnTgZBhYrwXicK8CeyaSSyVNUeraS0VWrPsycFCnDD7ESjPrET4LlS+TiBatzTTLWBWTqpXrObLJiEjejTUKRQsfT5JbDAzLSU6Ua7jR6oF6cT6-TbCdLxoiKWH+crI8afR49pkALoaGHGeDKeA6Ky2O0DSAAd0YmhYLP8-nekBQjGo+Cs0gHQ+QSkbmkYSmoVntUAAHsvHkY8LFCD1IG5UIRuAAnUxRrIAM0YyDEmhSx3VN2bYh6K6O3AwC43YKaN+Q8DwHgVFWdhj1YWBEBEWA-wAoDIE3QwCgQ20cXQVdGEsfQEK3ZgXxSeCf0GR4kP9LIxHQWJkGPVtHjfKAMGPABrb9CKgbddxSCQlHcZDHygGc5wXJcsNYqBYhY0TICvG871WZk+IWdi9wAR1YdAlEA3RAKoc9+WfV9sKyAAvKjuCsC9TGgwzCkMlCaUbMQTwk1ipOvW8UgFBTnCUlIlA-Bcz1s5DiPVOjIAY5jViPBc8F05wBO4edF2cmluEIdB4GYcSRNEjVtjAfwgsIuysmgl9YOUFKcTwbgkkAwgoJgwDKpyySfNWWAhLwryjG49BjwsWKcDwMDkB6-jZ0SoTMJsaznHXObq3GyAWvo7hwLQbgdOWtBCG3XzlB40SSJ-E7SIDH9wv6yKPjanc92ijSCNOvjIASpLhNulyHKc1qXPaqA-NQALkmW6T3I60tbK8lb0sy-a-sIyBGyUedmuAr7cqgMr-3RlIarqxgGpxiqVHGzYxSqOaSu9SmCuhwzIGyzH-vulJVPUzSdEYba5tcmSUmZIrTpC2iEKupiqrKAHIDA7rGZ+6jVmoU9xN48WRvU2ALxPVAaNEuiFivMQ3CVlnJJJvHVgJk2ica8q8ep4WwVrMEzsMV3EI6Ikux7PscHCKcOxHMcht9QcOwilJ+uQTAh0tuDEecUDwMghPVrCmWYqoro4qMd7pv1lyFsIz3oTjBYC+SpOjHXGvnHB2StE5V6ZYPI9T2SUWaWZsLG8FsVW7Z1YOY05hud5pG0IwqWskA+BGIAYXWp6tRhlWe3MyzkHVpGEFMAzJJM48zJwCyxCs4riKrewTqWjRkeUK9PpGSBp9gABNKrwoXABRVc3CrzAJOTIJ0kIFCAA).